# С++ Перевод строки содержащей HEX данные в char[]

Tags: c++, строки, char, hex

Добрый день!
Программирую отправку данных на специфический принтер и столкнулся с проблемой
На принтер нужно отправлять Тег пакеты

```
Char s[]={ 0x05, 0x06, 0xD1, 0xE0, 0xEC, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xE0 };
```

Если задать вручную то все работает. Но как мне правильно заполнить Char s[] из переменной?

Вариант перевода строки не работает:

```
std::string s6_str = "0x05, 0x06, 0xD1, 0xE0, 0xEC, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xE0";
s6 = new char [s6_str.length()+1];
std::strcpy (s6, s6_str.c_str());
```

Подскажите как быть!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы сильно усложняете задачу: вместо ""0x05, 0x06," пишите "0506". Перевод же HEX-цифр в значения тривиален.

Comment: По условию задачи обязательно хранить "Тег пакеты" в текстовом виде?

Comment: >По условию задачи обязательно хранить "Тег пакеты" в текстовом виде?     Главное чтобы в итоге массив char c hex внутри оказался...

Comment: Внутри, простите, чего?

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: Внутри char массива

Comment: Это к тому, что может вам сразу задавать массивы чаров, без лишних конвертаций.

Comment: Типа `std::vector<char> cmd0 = {0x02, 0x03, 0x04};`, `std::vector<char> cmd1 = {0x05, 0x06, 0x07};` и т.д.

Comment: Откуда у вас `s6_str` в таком формате берётся? Почему байты как ascii числа заданы? Можете ли вы входной формат поменять?

Comment: s6_str - взята для примера в таком формате. Входной формат - обычный текст. Привести нужно именно к ascii в HEX по другому железка не поймет. вообще в заданой строке первый байт это тег, второй длина передаваемой строки, дальше сама строка. т.е.фактически это 56самара. но передать ее нужно именно в таком виде s[]  { 0x05, 0x06, 0xD1, 0xE0, 0xEC, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xE0 };

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант:

```
сhar s[] = { 0x05, 0x06, 0xD1, 0xE0, 0xEC, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xE0 };`
```

хранит последовательность кодов. Общий размер составляет 8 байт.

Второй вариант:

```
std::string s = "0x05, 0x06, 0xD1, 0xE0, 0xEC, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xE0";
```

хранит строку в явно заданном виде. Общий размер ее составляет 47 байт (если мой калькулятор не ошибся).

Перевод из второго варианта в первый будет включать:

1. Разделение на подстроки (по запятой);
2. Перевод из строки в число, например, через [`stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/);
3. Заполнение нового массива полученными числами.

В общем случае вариант ответа на вопрос:

> как мне правильно заполнить Char s[] из переменной?

зависит от того в каком виде хранится эта "переменная".

Если просто нужно забить строку кодами, то и пишите в неё коды, а не строки:

```
std::string s = "\x05\x06\xD1\xE0\xEC\xE0\xF0\xE0";
```

Comment: Мне нужно наоборот получить char который будет содержать вот такие данные { 0x05, 0x06, 0xD1, 0xE0, 0xEC, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xE0 }.  Изначально беру обычную строку - кодирую ее в HEX и вот как эти HEX данные перевести в char не понимаю...причем тут данные не простые - 1 байт внутренний тег 2 байт размер текстовой строки все остальное сама текстовая строка...

Comment: @VersuS опишите более подробно, что понимается под `беру обычную строку - кодирую ее в HEX`. Добавьте это в свой вопрос, путем его редактирования. Мой вариант из шагов 1,2,3 Вас не устраивает?

Comment: А как реализовать данные шаги?

Comment: @VersuS 2 и 3 пункты, мне кажется должны быть очевидны. Для п.1 можно использовать `string::find` или более специфические функции обработки строк. Просто нельзя же в каждом ответе расписывать действия до элементарных. Должны быть какие-то базовые знания.

Comment: Разбить на подстроки не проблема. Но вот почему то когда пытаюсь заполнить массив  strcpy(s[i], str.c_str()); не выходит говорит: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'. Подскажите что не так делаю...

Comment: @VersuS потому что `s[i]` это символ (`char`), а `strcpy` работает со строками (`char*`).

Comment: А не подскажите функцию для заполнения s[i] это символ (char)?

Comment: @VersuS Обычное присваивание: `s[i] = 'a';`, `s[i] = 65;` и т.д.

Comment: да но s[i] = "0xF0"; не срабатывает

Comment: @VersuS потому что в двойных кавычках задается строка. Уберите кавычки и возьмите в руки учебник по C++.